# How to validate input on the show (GET) method of a Laravel resource controller?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In routes/api.php:

```
Route::resource('equipment', \App\Http\Controllers\EquipmentController::class)->only(['show']);
```

In app\Http\Controllers\EquipmentController:

```
public function show(Equipment $equipment): Response
{
    return new Response(new EquipmentResource($equipment));
}
```

The ID field of the database table for the Equipment model is an integer.

A successful request to the application:

```
/equipment/123
```

A request to the application which results in 500 server error:

```
/equipment/abc
```

```
"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: \"abc\" (SQL: select * from \"equipment\" where \"id\" = abc and \"equipment\".\"deleted_at\" is null limit 1)",
```

How can I make Laravel validate the input and return a nice error, rather than the unhelpful one that it does now?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hi. I actually have more methods than show but I made my code more concise for my question

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ The code in your second comment gives me `array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given`

Comment: Ok I think I found it. For resource routes you should pass the parameter as an array:

`Route::resource('equipment', EquipmentController::class)->where(['equipment' => '[0-9]+']);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ That's changed my 500 server error into 401 Unauthenticated

Comment: Just adding `->where(['equipment' => '[0-9]+'])` change the status? That's weird. I you remove it, does it work as before?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes

Comment: May `missing` method help you out.  for more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#customizing-missing-model-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Use `missing` method to redirect when id not matched

see the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#customizing-missing-model-behavior

```
Route::resource( 'equipment', \App\Http\Controllers\EquipmentController::class )->only( [ 'show' ] )
        ->missing( function ( Request $request ) {
            return Redirect::route( 'some.custom.error.response-or-page' );
        } );
```

Comment: Will this work for submitting string instead of integer? Or just for a missing model with integer ID?

Comment: Yes it will work for anything but genuine id